# Task/algorithm of template method

Tags: oop

I'd like to use the Template Method Pattern for drawing shapes GUI. Any suggestion as to what can be the task of the Template Method in the abstract class Shape? I mean, what can this method produce? 
Thank you.

Comment: Start with drawing shapes. Refactor to some pattern later, if you will have duplicated code. Don't try implementing patterns before you faced problems.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I wouldn't use Template Method pattern for this task but that's the specification.

Comment: Then I suggest to set start and end points of shape, and call Draw method which will be different for each shape.

Answer (score 0):

Draw method. Since every shape has different specification in rendering.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think this can be done in only one method. I can't see what the steps before drawing are.

Comment: Just to clarify, What I meant is that, there is an empty/abstract method named Draw inside the template class (Shape), and this method can be override in the implementation.

Comment: I think it's easier to implement an interface instead of having an abstract class if I only have a draw method which is different for every subclass of Shape. I'm trying to find an algorithm with some steps- methods identically implemented for all the sub classes and  some that will be overridden.

Comment: That's another option. You can go for an abstract (template) or an interface or even both.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to the below example, i made comments in the code. hope it helps to you...

**CustomShape.java  -  your abstract class**

```
public abstract class CustomShape extends View {
    int shapeType = 0;
    int clr = Color.BLACK;
    int x=0;
    int y=0;

    public CustomShape(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    // OnDraw can act as Template Method
    // This method holds the algorithm of shape creation    
    // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    @Override
    final public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
            // you can put here more method to make your shape different                 
            // for example setColor(); setStroke() ..... 

        createRectangle(canvas);                
    }

   // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


    // Primitive operation sub classes must override
    abstract void setShapeType(int type);

    // Primitive operation sub classes must override
    abstract void setShapeColor(int color);

    // Primitive operation sub classes must override
    abstract void setXY(int x1,int y1);


    // Concreate Operation we dont want subclass to override  
    final void createRectangle(Canvas canvas) {

        if (shapeType == 0) {
            if (isColored()) {
                canvas.drawRect(x, y, x+100, y+100, getPaint(clr, 1));
            } else {
                canvas.drawRect(x, y, x+100, y+100, getPaint(Color.BLACK, 1));

            }
        } else {
            if (isColored()) {
                canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 80, getPaint(clr, 1));
            } else {
                canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 80, getPaint(clr, 1));
            }
        }
    }




    // Concreate Operation we dont want subclass to override  

    final Paint getPaint(int color, int Stroke) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(color);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(Stroke);
        return paint;
    }


    // HOOK - sub class can override but doesnt have to, 

    boolean isColored() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

**CustomShape1.java  - your concreate class**

```
public class CustomShape1 extends CustomShape {

    public CustomShape1(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }   

     boolean isColored(){
         return true;
     }


    @Override
    void setShapeType(int type) {
        shapeType= type;
    }

    @Override
    void setShapeColor(int color) {
        clr = color;        
    }

    @Override
    void setXY(int x1, int y1) {
        x = x1;
        y =y1;
    }


}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout ln1,ln2;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ln1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ln1);
        ln2= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ln2);

        CustomShape1 cs1 = new CustomShape1(this);
        cs1.setShapeType(1);
        cs1.setShapeColor(Color.YELLOW);
        cs1.setXY(100, 100);

        CustomShape1 cs2 = new CustomShape1(this);
        cs2.setShapeType(0);
        cs2.setShapeColor(Color.RED);
        cs2.setXY(300, 300);


        ln2.addView(cs2);
        ln1.addView(cs1);        

    }  
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ln1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ln2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```